# bot meant to randomly tag someone in server only tags itself

Tags: discord, discord.py

im trying to get a discord bot "test wall" to tag a random person on slash command, but for some reason it only tags itself, i want it to be able to tag itself but not *only* itself

```
slash = SlashCommand(client, sync_commands=True)

@slash.slash(name="MirrorMirrorOnTheWall", guild_ids=[828901543092682803])
async def MirrorMirrorOnTheWall(ctx): 
    await ctx.send(choice(tuple(member.mention for member in ctx.guild.members)))
```

i cannot begin to figure out why, so i assume it's something im completely unaware of. if there's nothing wrong with that code, [this is the full bot file](https://www.mediafire.com/file/punfjpq3tvvu38e/main.py/file)

[me attempting to use the command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FbfRk.png)

Comment: Do you have the guild members intent enabled? If not, the member cache will not be populated properly and the only available choice might be the bot client itself

Comment: yes i do, i should have mentioned it in the post but that was the first (and only) thing i was able to think of and fix, and it was not the issue

Comment: Looking at your full file, I don't see the member intent being enabled on the bot side. You'll need to both enable the privileged intent on the discord developer page and pass it to your client on initialization for it to take effect

Comment: that worked, i didn't know it had to be enabled bot side.